# Dynamically create crystal report columns

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I have created a cross tab report to create a report dynamically according to the user's selected column.

But I have got a serious problem, I <strike>wanna</strike> want to hide other fields when those fields are empty (no data to show).

The schema for that report:

```
<xs:element name="salseSummary">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="A1" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A2" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A3" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A4" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A5" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A6" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A7" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A8" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A9" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A10" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A11" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A12" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A13" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A14" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A15" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A16" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A17" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A18" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A19" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="A20" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="TOTAL" type="xs:decimal"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Here is the way how I map those columns to the report
 [image]

This is how I set the custom styles
[image]

But when I run it, this is how it displays the result.
[image]

Comment: I guess you need to check options supress `lables`, `sub totals` and `empty rows` for rows and columns...have you tried these options?

Comment: yes, I've tried like above pic2

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have the same fields in both the `rows` and `columns` sections--choose one.